# Sort people by their phone number Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to get people by their mobilePhone number with graph api in dotnet.

I can I actually get all people who have a mobilePhone defined ?

the object for phones is :

```
"phones": [
{
"type": "business",
"value": "....."
}
{
"type": "mobilePhone",
"value":"0672737473"
}
]
```

As you can see it is in an array. I would like to get all people who have the mobile Phone number because business does not concerns my app.

I could get all contacts with paging but I would prefer not having to sort users on my side.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [$orderby](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#orderby-parameter) parameter?

Comment: Hum it doesn't seem to fit my needs because I want to exclude people. I would you do it ? Order could be use if I understand to order poeple by a property and then because you order them you get the first contacts that have a mobile phone defined ?

Comment: The property 'Phones' does not support filtering. I'm afraid that you have to handle users on your side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mobilePhone doesnot support filtering, it is correctly suggested by @Allen Wu.
You can find the details in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Yeah graph api is still pretty much limited that's shame. I hope it will change soon because this kind of filter would have made my app better than just sorting by user name.